# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy' in flask & celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am having a huge data set in `elasticsearch` which I need to export in `csv` as per the end user's request. End user will send a query which would filter out my `elasticsearch` data & generate the results. Since the `csv` files are big and there are much more processing time I want to run this process in background.

To implement this I created a `flask` app & integrated the `celery` module. My `celery` process accepts the `request` parameters & start the background processing of csv.

Below is my code -

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from task import make_celery
import json, sys, time, pandas, boto3
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan 

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='sqs://AKIARYGF4GTjnjkKJXHHR:EkLmCgD3Ch+0AqLe+cdlTwnknkXwVMbkSAG4Jm@',
)
celery = make_celery(app)

@app.route("/export", methods=['POST','GET'])
def process():

    exportList.delay(index=request.args['index'], query=request.args['query'] , export_id=request.args['export_id'])

    return 'I sent async request!'

@celery.task(name='example.exportList')
def exportList(index, query, export_id):
    start_time = time.time()
    
    print("\ncreating client instance of Elasticsearch")
    elastic_client = Elasticsearch(['xyz-test-5q76b4fabvhjjbhjbjbjb2bt6xrhhsi.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com'],
                                   http_auth=('test', '854852@123$%'),
                                   scheme="https",
                                   port=443,
                                   )
                                   
    
    scan_docs = pandas.DataFrame()

    for hit in scan(elastic_client, index=index, query=query):
        scan_source_data = hit["_source"]
        scan_id = hit["_id"]
        scan_doc_data = pandas.Series(scan_source_data, name=scan_id)
        scan_docs = scan_docs.append(scan_doc_data)

    scan_docs.to_csv("/tmp/scandocs.csv", ",")
    
    """
    Further intimating the user that the file is ready via email
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I am getting an error in my `celery` console

```
[2021-08-17 07:24:15,229: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task example.exportList[1d30ab46-f4de-408a-8add-e3b98d633bef] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'str' objec
t has no attribute 'copy'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celery/task.py", line 14, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celery/example.py", line 47, in exportList
    for hit in scan(elastic_client, index=index, query=query):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 550, in scan
    query = query.copy() if query else {}
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Comment: you are passing "str" as query here `for hit in scan(elastic_client, index=index, query=query):` but sorry i coudnt find any mistake in your code

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/695

Comment: I don’t know Elasticsearch, but it looks like its `query` shouldn’t be a string…?